# ORA-25128: No insert/update/delete on table with constraint (...CK_AM_DATA) disabled and validated

Tags: oracle

I searched in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-25128%3A+) and I noticed this error was not covered.

There is an old table in the database (not created by me) when I try to do DML changes it throws that error.

this is my below reproduced scenario.

```
drop table AM_DATA
/
create table AM_DATA
(id number(4) null,
 name varchar2 (200) null)
/
alter table AM_DATA
 add constraint  CK_AM_DATA
 check (1=1)
 disable validate
/
insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(1,'A')
/
insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(2,'B')
/
insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(3,'B')
/
delete AM_DATA where id =3
/
commit
/
select count(1) cnt from AM_DATA
/



SQL> 

Table dropped

Table created

Table altered

insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(1,'A')

ORA-25128: No insert/update/delete on table with constraint (....CK_AM_DATA) disabled and validated

insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(2,'B')

ORA-25128: No insert/update/delete on table with constraint (....CK_AM_DATA) disabled and validated

insert into AM_DATA(id,name) values(3,'B')

ORA-25128: No insert/update/delete on table with constraint (....CK_AM_DATA) disabled and validated

delete AM_DATA where id =3

ORA-25128: No insert/update/delete on table with constraint (.....CK_AM_DATA) disabled and validated

Commit complete

       CNT
----------
         0
```

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1096283

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you for your link but I already planning to answer my question for future reader.

Answer (score 4):

Well the error is obvious, the checking constraint it seems disabled and validated.

By default when constraint is disabled, its `novalidated`, however you can specify it by `validated` however you have to understand why this being validated? usually when you want to prevent execution of DML's on a table, you can add a checking constraint disabled with validated.
So it seems this constraint was created for purpose read only especially the checking condition (1=1) is always true so it will not do anything.

To solve this error: You can run the below command, the checking constraint is still disabled but you can do dml changes on it.

```
alter table
   AM_DATA
DISABLE novalidate constraint
    CK_AM_DATA;
```